# "this" argument in boost bind

Tags: multithreading, boost, bind

I am writing multi-threaded server that handles async read from many tcp sockets. Here is the section of code that bothers me.

```
void data_recv (void) {
    socket.async_read_some (
            boost::asio::buffer(rawDataW, size_t(648*2)),
            boost::bind ( &RPC::on_data_recv, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
} // RPC::data_recvW


void on_data_recv (boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytesRx) {

     if ( rawDataW[bytesRx-1] == ENDMARKER {  // <-- this code is fine
         process_and_write_rawdata_to_file    
         }

     else {
        read_socket_until_endmarker            //  <-- HELP REQUIRED!!
        process_and_write_rawadata_to_file
        }
}
```

Nearly always the async_read_some reads in data including the endmarker, so it works fine. Rarely, the endmarker's arrival is delayed in the stream and that's when my program fails. I think it fails because I have not understood how boost bind works.

My first question:
I am confused with this [boost totorial example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) , in which "this" does not appear in the handler declaration. ( Please see code of start_accept() in the example.) How does this work? Does compiler ignore the "this" ?

my second question:
In the on_data_recv() method, how do I read data from the same socket that was read in the on_data() method? In other words, how do I pass the socket as argument from calling method to the handler? when the handler is executed in another thread? Any help in form of a few lines of code that can fit into my "read_socket_until_endmarker" will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question: I am confused with this boost totorial example , in which "this" does not appear in the handler declaration. ( Please see code of start_accept() in the example.) How does this work? Does compiler ignore the "this" ?

In the example (and I'm assuming this holds for your functions as well) the `start_accept()` is a member function. The `bind` function is conveniently designed such that when you use `&` in front of its first argument, it interprets it as a member function that is applied to its second argument.

So while a code like this:

```
void foo(int x) { ... }
bind(foo, 3)();
```

Is equivalent to just calling `foo(3)`

Code like this:

```
struct Bar { void foo(int x); }
Bar bar;
bind(&foo, &bar, 3)(); // <--- notice the & before foo
```

Would be equivalent to calling `bar.foo(3)`.

And thus as per your example

```
boost::bind ( &RPC::on_data_recv, this, // <--- notice & again
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
```

When this object is invoked inside Asio it shall be equivalent to calling `this->on_data_recv(error, size)`. Checkout [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_pointers_to_memb) for more info.

For the second part, it is not clear to me how you're working with multiple threads, do you run `io_service.run()` from more than one thread (possible but I think is beyond your experience level)? It might be the case that you're confusing async IO with multithreading. I'm gonna assume that is the case and if you correct me I'll change my answer.

The usual and [preferred](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/master/mon/thinking_asynchronously.pdf) starting point is to have just one thread running the `io_service.run()` function. Don't worry, this will allow you to handle many sockets asynchronously.

If that is the case, your two functions could easily be modified as such:

```
void data_recv (size_t startPos = 0) {
    socket.async_read_some (
            boost::asio::buffer(rawDataW, size_t(648*2)) + startPos,
            boost::bind ( &RPC::on_data_recv, this,
                    startPos,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
} // RPC::data_recvW


void on_data_recv (size_t startPos,
                   boost::system::error_code ec,
                   std::size_t bytesRx) {
     // TODO: Check ec

     if (rawDataW[startPos + bytesRx-1] == ENDMARKER) {
         process_and_write_rawdata_to_file    
     }
     else {
        // TODO: Error if startPos + bytesRx == 648*2
        data_recv(startPos + bytesRx);
     }
}
```

Notice though that the above code still has problems, the main one being that if the other side sent two messages quickly one after another, we could receive (in one async_read_some call) the full first message + part of the second message, and thus missing the ENDMARKER from the first one. Thus it is not enough to only test whether the last received byte is == to the ENDMARKER.

I could go on and modify this function further (I think you might get the idea on how), but you'd be better off using [async_read_until](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) which is meant exactly for this purpose.